# How to find max of column in 3D array based on condition in another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, max

I have an array with 3 columns and need to find the maximum of the first column where the third column is less than some predefined value.

## Input, E.g.:

a = [[ 1   2   1], [ 2   3   3], [ 7  10   5], [ 5   1   2], [ 2   3   4]]

## Desired output

max(a[:,0], where a[:,2] < 5) = [5 1 2]

How to do this? Preferably as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argmax`:

```
subset = a[a[:, 2] < 5]
result = subset[subset[:, 0].argmax()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[5 1 2]
```

This gets the subset of the original array based on the given condition, finds the index of the row with the highest value in the first column with slicing and `argmax`, and uses that value to index the subset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `argmax`

```
a[(a[:,0] * (a[:,2] < 5).astype(int)).argmax(),:]
Out[946]: array([5, 1, 2])
```